# Add string to url on page load (javascript/jquery)

Tags: jquery, html

Looking to add a string to all urls in a particular div upon page load for marketing purposes, however my code does not appear to be working sadly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var trail = '?cid=marketing-string';
$("#sample-div").find('a').attr('href') + trail;
});
```

Desired result would be turning:

```
<div id="sample-div">
  <a href="http://www.example.com">
</div>
```

Into

```
<div id="sample-div">
  <a href="http://www.example.com?cid=marketing-string">
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add string to url on page load with jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703078/add-string-to-url-on-page-load-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set attribute value you have to pass value as second parameter in [`attrib()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.

[`.attr( attributeName, value )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

Consider following:

```
var trail = '?cid=marketing-string';
$("#sample-div").find('a').attr('href', $("#sample-div").find('a').attr('href') + trail);
```

Above code is equivalent to :

```
var trail = '?cid=marketing-string';
var url = $("#sample-div").find('a').attr('href');
$("#sample-div").find('a').attr('href', url + trail);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/50ucd131/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`attr-attributeName-function`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function):

```
$("#sample-div").find('a').attr('href', function(i, val){
    return val + trail;
});
```

Your code issue is that you are getting the href correctly like

```
$("#sample-div").find('a').attr('href');
```

Then concatenating `trail` to it correctly, but after that you are not setting it anywhere. So, that's why your code doesn't work.

[**`FIDDLE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/uzb7b9nc/)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the selector to gather any link located throughout your page and append the text to each through this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#sample-div a').each(function () {
      this.href += '?cid=marketing-string';
  })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v5w27yso/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/xqbxpqbs/)**

Here is the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var trail = '?cid=marketing-string';
  var original = $("#sample-div").find('a').attr('href');
  $("#sample-div").find('a').attr('href', original + trail);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample-div">
  <a href="http://www.example.com" >Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery .. I have tried in a sample MVC application

```
$("a[href^='http://example.com']")
   .each(function () {
       this.href = this.href.replace(/^http:\/\/example\.com/,
         "http://www.example.com?cid=marketing-string");
   });
```